# image.subtract is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, function

[Link to GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c75267a9cd4913e23118e649c776495d)

```js
function BAI(Im){
  var pcr = 0.1
  var pir = Im.select('B3')
  var pcnir = 0.06
  var pinir = Im.select('B4')
  var one = 1
  var bai = one.divide(pcr.subtract(pir).pow(2).add(pcnir.subtract(pinir).pow(2)))
  return bai
}
var BAIColle = LSatTMCf.map(BAI)
```

When running this code, the Error "pcr.subtract is not a function". I guess the issue is with `pcr` being a number and `pir` being a Pixel Value from an Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an image with a constant value for each of your parameters. Furthermore, you forgot to filter your image-collection by the bounds of your aoi (https://code.earthengine.google.com/c0ff852ccc0e1b9811314f2bc2743cd6):

```
//Filter ImageCollections
var LSatTMCf = LSatTMC.filterDate('2008-01-01','2008-12-31').filterBounds(aoi);

//Center Map
Map.centerObject(aoi, 10);

function BAI(Im){
  var pcr = ee.Image(0.1)
  var pir = Im.select('B3')
  var pcnir = ee.Image(0.06)
  var pinir = Im.select('B4')
  var one = ee.Image(1)
  var bai = one.divide(pcr.subtract(pir).pow(2).add(pcnir.subtract(pinir).pow(2)))
  return bai
}
var BAIColle = LSatTMCf.map(BAI)

print(BAIColle)

Map.addLayer(BAIColle.first())
```