# Error with equation in GEE

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, calculate-values

I'm trying to calculate values for a raster I have based on other raster values.

The problem is that I get the error:

> -0.054.multiply is not a function

and I believe it is because I'm writing something wrong, but can't find the problem.

This is how I try to calculate the new values for the raster:

```
var NewRas=(2.12).subtract((-0.054).multiply(RAS1))+((0.12).multiply(RAS2)).add((3.14).multiply(RAS3));
```

My end goal is to calculate the new pixel values for my new raster base on this equation:

EDIT: I have managed to calculate it this way, as demonstrated in GEE tutorial:
[image]

**But still I don't understand why what I wrote is wrong**

Comment: Related post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/299835/68792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping all of your float values with `ee.Image.constant()` to make them `ee.Image` objects. The problem is that you are calling Earth Engine math methods on client-side values that have no such methods.